# How to build an internal messenger in Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, cron

I am building an internal messenger for a site with Laravel 9.
I want to be able to send messages to my users. unilaterally
But how does this work?
If I have 4000 users, should a copy of the message be inserted in the database for each user?
Or connect a message with a pivot table to the user table?
If users delete the message, how do I know

which users I sent the message to?
How should this be done so that the server does not time out or crash?
Doesn't the capacity of the database run out with this?
What is the right way?

Comment: We have a similar issue with notifications. We create a message once for all users (1 database entry) and when each user decides to read it then we create a copy for that user so they can mark it as read/delete it etc (we soft delete so we know not to make it again). It works for us because the majority of users don't really read them

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 tables, `Rooms` and `Messages`. `Rooms` to group who are the users in the chat (can be more than two in one room) then `Messages` with `room_id` as foreign key. You can also add read by recipients in your messages to view who read your messages. Just paginate your messages when they scroll up to load the next page.

`rooms migration`

```
Schema::create('chat_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('_uuid', 50);
    $table->string('chat_initiator', 50);
    $table->json('user_ids');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`messages migration`

```
Schema::create('chat_messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('_uuid', 50);
    $table->string('chat_room_id', 50);
    $table->string('posted_by_user', 50);
    $table->json('message');
    $table->json('read_by_recipients');
    $table->string('type', 10);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Since you are using json as field, add this in your models

```
protected $casts = [
    'column_here' => 'array',
];
```

`Rooms` table:

[image: ROOMS]

`Messages` table:

[image: MESSAGES]